# Push to main instead of master from eclipse to git

Tags: eclipse, github, push, commit

I have been searching and I found git commands to change the repository but I'm new on github and I don't know how to make that from eclipse, everytime I push I make the changes on the master branch instead of the default main, when I try to push the main it says non fast forward and I can't do it, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Select Team > Advanced > Rename Branch
Rename local as main
Rename remote to main

Answer (score 2):

when you first commit your project in eclipse and then you click on push
after filling the information of the repository you get this
[image]

you will write main here insted of master and your project will be pushed directly to the default main
my solution is only when you first upload your project to GitHub

Comment: I new I could do that by I didn't want to make a new repository